# React "cannot destructure property"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, jsx, destructuring

So i am trying to learn React and i am following a tutorial, i follow along and the i do everything as in the tutorial, the person saves the changes and it compiles, but mine gives out this error:
`TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'text' of 'seasonConfig[season]' as it is undefined.`

Here is the component i am trying to render:

```
import React from 'react';

const seasonConfig = {
  summer: {
    text: '',
    iconName: 'sun'
  },
  winter: {
    text: '',
    iconName: 'snowflake'
  }
};

const getSeason = (lat, month) => {
  if (month > 2 && month < 9) {
    return lat > 0 ? 'summer ' : 'winter';
  } else {
    return lat > 0 ? 'winter ' : 'summer';
  }
};

const SeasonDisplay = (props) => {
  const season = getSeason(props.lat, new Date().getMonth());
  const { text, iconName } = seasonConfig[season];

  return (
    <div>
      <i className={` massive ${iconName} icon`} />
      <h1>{text}</h1>
      <i className={` massive ${iconName} icon`} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default SeasonDisplay;
```

Comment: can you `console.log` season ?

Comment: i placed the console.log after the season const and i got  "summer" then a new line and "summer" again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the space after summer and winter in the if conditions:

```js
const getSeason = (lat, month) => {
  if (month > 2 && month < 9) {
    return lat > 0 ? 'summer' : 'winter'; // 'summer ' => 'summer'
  } else {
    return lat > 0 ? 'winter' : 'summer'; // 'winter ' => 'winter'
  }
};
```

OR if we really need the space, could also do `seasonConfig[season.trim()]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:
import { React } from "react";

const seasonConfig = {
  Summer: {
    text: "Lets hit beach",
    iconName: "sun",
  },
  Winter: {
    text: " Its Winter",
    iconName: "snowflake",
  },
};

const getSeason = (lat, month) => {
  if (month > 2 && month < 9) {
    return lat > 0 ? "summer" : "winter";
  } else {
    return lat > 0 ? "winter" : "summer";
  }
};
const SeasonDisplay = (props) => {
  const season = getSeason(props.lat, new Date().getMonth());
  console.log(season);
  const text = season === "winter" ? "Burr, Its Chilly" : "Lets hit th e beach";
  const icon = season === "winter" ? "snowflake icon" : "sun icon";

  return (
    <div>
      <i className={icon} />
      <h1>{text}</h1>

      <i className={icon} />
    </div>
  );
};
export default SeasonDisplay;
```